# How do I render my pug files to html on the client-side instead of server-side

Tags: javascript, pug, client-side, templating

I have an existing webpage in HTML, CSS, JavaScript & JQuery without a server-side but at the moment I want to use pug to render my views from the client-side without having to serve the files from the server.

If I were to render my views from the server, I know how to go about it but my main concern is doing it from the client-side.

I know I have to use the `pug-cli` to achieve that. I've gone through the API documentation: https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html but I don't seem to grab it. 
I would love if I can get a better and simpler explanation of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the library and load it in your HTML with a `<script>` tag. You can download it with npm (`npm install pug`) or from https://github.com/pugjs/pug/releases.
2. Use the [`render()`](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html#pugrendersource-options-callback) function to transform pug code into HTML.